# What spanning tree IEEE protocol does the Cisco 1252AG Aironet access point support?

Tags: cisco, wireless, cisco-ios, spanning-tree, cisco-wireless

[Link to data sheet](https://www.andovercg.com/datasheets/cisco-aironet-1250-series-access-point.pdf)

We're running Cisco IOS version 15.2(2)JA1. What version of the IEEE STP is supported on the Cisco Aironet 1252AG access points? We are using the "bridge X protocol ieee" command.

```
bridge 1 priority 8192
bridge 1 protocol ieee
bridge 1 route ip
bridge 2 priority 8192
bridge 2 protocol ieee
bridge 3 priority 8192
bridge 3 protocol ieee
bridge 4 priority 8192
bridge 4 protocol ieee
bridge 5 priority 8192
bridge 5 protocol ieee

ap(config)#bridge 1 protocol ?
  dec          DEC protocol
  ibm          IBM protocol
  ieee         IEEE 802.1 protocol
  vlan-bridge  vlan-bridge protocol

ap(config)#bridge 1 protocol
```

Comment: Should be RSTP, considering the 1250 family's age. MSTP is not supported.

Comment: 802.1d https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ibm-technologies/source-route-transparent-srt-bridging/10676-37.html